# Узнать входит ли цвет в заданный промежуток

Tags: php, математика

К примеру у нас есть цвет в HEX формате #0000FF или RGB, не суть. И есть синий цвет, диапазон которого я определил как от #F8F8FF до #002366. На основании [этих данных](http://www.workwithcolor.com/blue-color-hue-range-01.htm)

Как узнать входит ли #0000FF в этот диапазон с помощью PHP? Возможно не HEX, а RGB. Или какие там еще варианты есть?

Comment: В указанной схеме кодирования цвет - трёхмерный. А теперь подумай - как можно в трёх измерениях задать диапазон ДВУМЯ ТОЧКАМИ?

Comment: @Akina вершины диагонали прямоугольного параллелепипеда

Comment: @andreymal Две точки не определяют нужный параллелепипед однозначно. А если взять параллелепипед, грани коего формально параллельны координатным плоскостям, то легко убедиться, что остальные вершины - крайне сомнительно "синие"... тогда уж скорее есть смысл говорить о шаре, заданном двумя вершинами его диаметра. Но и тут всё зыбко, ибо отнесение цвета к одному из базовых - это ощущение, а не математика... сплошь и рядом разные люди по-разному называют один и тот же цвет.

Comment: @Akina тогда можно попробовать преобразовать в какие-нибудь HSV/HSB/HSL, которые немножко ближе к человеческим ощущениям (хотя да, я не специалист по цветам)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$blueRange = array(
    'F8F8FF',
    'CCCCFF',
    'C4C3D0',
    '92A1CF',
    '8C92AC',
    '0000FF',
    '2A52BE',
    '002FA7',
    '003399',
    '00009C',
    '120A8F',
    '00008B',
    '000080',
    '191970',
    '082567',
    '002366'
);

if(in_array('0000FF', $blueRange)){
    # Входит
}else{
    # Не входит
}
```

Или так: https://repl.it/@ReaGed/rustackoverflowcomquestions875078

Comment: Супер, спасибо. Пошел разбираться :)